# Change input file extension to lowercase

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I want to upload files with a lowercase extension, even if the user chooses a file with uppercase extension. I use an `<input type="file"/>` for file choosing.

Here's an example:

**Before**
`(abc.CSV), (def.cSV), (ghi.cSv)`

**After**
`(abc.csv), (def.csv), (ghi.csv)`

Underneath is a screenshot of the file chooser.

[image: Screenshot of the file chooser]

Comment: Why you need it in uppercase ?

Comment: @MohammadAdil, I think he needs it in lowercase even if the file uses uppercase.

Comment: what is serverside technology

Comment: Handle this with php : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strtolower.php

Comment: Update the server side code to handle files in a lower case.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot manipulate the **actual value** of file input fields on client-side, due to security restrictions.

Your only option is to handle this on the server-side.

---

You can only **read** its value. If you simply want the **displayed** text to be in lowercase, then there are many ways to do it, but the **uploaded** file will still honour the original name, then you'll have to process it on server-side.

Comment: thanks am also think it now

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to check if the user selected a file with a proper file extension in lowercase, you can use below snippet to pattern your work.

```
 var file = $("#fileupload").val();

        if (file == '') {
                $("#errDiv").html("Please select a file first.");
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
        }
        else {
                var ext = file.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                if ($.inArray(ext, ['xlsx']) == -1) {    //not .XLsx or otherwise
                $("#errDiv").html("Please select valid file type(xlsx).");
                return false;
            }
```

Lastly, you MUST really check the file uploaded in the backend and see if its a valid extension and most importantly, a valid file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [CSS text-transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp) property.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    input.lowercase{text-transform:lowercase;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    FILENAME <input class = "lowercase" id ="filename" type="text" name="filename">

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: type="file" please read again

Comment: This **transforms** the text **style**. But the **actual value** will be unchanged. Not sure if this is exactly what the OP wants. We will need his confirmation

Comment: Just as a side not, text-transform is not a `CSS3` property. It is a `CSS` property that has been around since `CSS1`...